# Issues with ConcurrentMutationLimitExceeded with AWS VPN creation in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-vpn

I am looking for some help to be pointed in the right direction. I am working on a module to create a VPN from an existing VPC and am running into with from AWS when applying the configuration.

`Error: Error creating Client VPN network association: ConcurrentMutationLimitExceeded: Cannot initiate another change for this endpoint at this time. Please try again later.`

From what I gather, it looks like Terraform is spinning up the network associations in parallel and causing AWS to trip on the simultaneous requests.

This seems pretty "standard" as it is being deployed in `us-east-2` across 3 AZs (`us-east-2a`, `us-east-2b`, and `us-east-2c`), so it feels a bit suspect that initiating these 3 calls simultaneously would be the root issue. A workaround with running with less parallelism might work be feels a bit hacky.

```
resource "aws_ec2_client_vpn_network_association" "main" {
  for_each               = data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids
  client_vpn_endpoint_id = aws_ec2_client_vpn_endpoint.main.id
  subnet_id              = each.key
  security_groups        = [aws_security_group.vpn_access.id]
}
```

A fully spike of the module is available here: https://gist.github.com/bobbrez/0e1bcb4ef376c2b7ebfed9061a74ff19